# How to debug code with dev tools that purposefully has a constant loop of debugger;?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

In some code I'm trying to debug, there is a portion of it that looks like this:

```
(function() {
    (function(f) {
        (function a() {
            try {
                function b(i) {
                    if (('' + (i / i)).length !== 1 || i % 20 === 0) {
                        (function() {}
                        ).constructor('debugger')();
                    } else {
                        debugger ;
                    }
                    b(++i);
                }
                b(0);
            } catch (e) {
                f.setTimeout(a, 5000)
            }
        })()
    })(document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('frame')).contentWindow);
}
)
```

Whenever you open the developer tools, it will constantly break on that. In chrome, you can disable all breakpoints to get past this, but you can't set breakpoints anywhere else in the code. In firefox, I cannot get past this, ever if I disable all breakpoints it seems to infinitely break in here.

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766524/firefox-disable-debugger-keywords/39784526.

Comment: ... with the difference that that question only targets Firebug and the Firefox DevTools.

Comment: Use Fiddler or similar debugging MitM proxy to alter the site response and replace `debugger;` with `/*debugger*/`.