# breakpoint triggers repeatedly after firebug opening

Tags: javascript, firebug

When I open firebug on one site, I can not analyse anything because every a few seconds a break-point triggers on that line:

```js
(function() {
  (function a() {
    try {
      (function b(i) {
        if (('' + (i / i)).length !== 1 || i % 20 === 0) {
          (function() {}).constructor('debugger')();
        } else {
          debugger;
        }
        b(++i);
      }(0))
    } catch (e) {
      setTimeout(a, 5000)
    }
  })()
})();
```

The button `enable/disable breakpoints` doesn't work.

I can not turn it off. How to disable it?

Comment: You have to `remove` `debugger` from code.

Comment: Search for debugger statement in your code and remove it

Comment: How do I suppose to do that? This is not my site, I do not have a access to the sources.

Comment: May be the objective of this code is to annoy you :) put a breakpoint at the beginning of this function and skip executing the same.

Comment: I want to analyze that site requests so I need a debugger :) It looks like a defense from such events )

Comment: Thats some defence as, even if dev tools are closed, function will execute and go in a never ending loop and will throw `maximum call stack exceed` error. But then `catch` will catch it and again register the same stuff after 5 secs. Seems more like a malware to me.

Comment: When debugger is closed everything works just fine. But if not debugger hangs and I can not see any network activities. Is there a way to turn it of?

Comment: @Rainmaker check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17yhekkk/1/). This seems to be a good security check. Yes this will add a delay, but its an interesting code.

Comment: Note te very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39766524/432681.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug *does* allow to break this vicious circle by creating a disabled breakpoint on that line:

[image: Disable <code>debugger</code> keyword in Firebug by placing a disabled breakpoint]

**But** [Firebug is going away](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/). So what you are actually seeing are probably the Firefox DevTools (using the Firebug theme) and those tools don't provide this feature yet. Therefore [I've asked for it some time ago](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html/issues/828) and there's also [another related bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925269).

See also [my answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39784526/432681).

Comment: You're right. But don't you know what the purpose of such breakpoints in the code? Security feature or smth else?

Comment: The authors of the website obviously want to block other people from inspecting their code, as several developer tools do not allow you to skip the `debugger` keyword.