# Preventing users to enter into developers tools

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript we can prevent user from pressing various keys, that I know.
But a disabled key such as `F12` can prevent user to access to developer tools or say preventing user to right click can do the same. It's a very good idea from security point of view, then why all major sites don't implement such scenario in order to protect their hard works such as various CSS and Designing.

I want a logical answer. If any reference for the sites with such implementation is needed then tell me I'll update my question with that link.

Comment: It's not a very good idea from a security point of view. You can't rely on client side security.

Comment: You can't prevent anything like that. There's always a way around it. People can enter their modifications and read your settings via javascript:mymodifications.here() in the adressbar of the browser if you managed a hack around it.

Comment: It's not a very good idea but this way we can prevent users from interacting with our UI. Then why not.?

Comment: For the same reason it wouldn't be a good idea to allow devs to disable keys such as Alt-F4.

Comment: All you have to do to bypass any of this is go to the browser menu and View Source. It's an annoyance at most. People who know what to do with the source code will also know how to get to it.

Comment: Or use `curl` to download the resources directly (or write your own browser that doesn't have such restrictions).

Comment: You can try the hack in given post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801175/breakpoint-triggers-repeatedly-after-firebug-opening#. Its interestingly annoying to debug with such code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are keys you can't intercept, and ways into devtools that you can't intercept (e.g., via menus).

If you're tring to protect your code or some such, you just can't, full stop. Anything that goes to the client is accessible to the user.

If you're trying to prevent the user getting themselves into trouble in devtools, you might do what Facebook does, which is output a big bold message to the console warning users not to use it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Answer is as simple as it gets: user can simply disable js, so why even bother spending resources on function, that can be disabled.